# LGSideMenuController Version 2 to 3 Update: Cannot find 'swipeGestureArea' in scope

Tags: ios, swift

Background: complete Swift/iOS development noob.

Trying to update an existing iOS project to latest minimum supported versions and I am encountering the `Cannot find 'swipeGestureArea' in scope` error for `swipeGestureArea = .full` that utilizes `LGSideMenuController`.

Note: the project I am updated `LGSideMenuController` pod update from version 2.1.1 to 3.1.2.

```
import UIKit
import LGSideMenuController

class SideMenuController: LGSideMenuController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        swipeGestureArea = .full // error
   }
}
```

I cannot find documentation for `swipeGestureArea`, but I found [this](https://github.com/AnkitGabani/LGSideMenu/blob/master/MainViewController) which shows that `swipeGestureArea = .full` is supposedly valid (line 146).

What would be the appropriate replacement for `swipeGestureArea` then?

Would it be setting both `leftViewSwipeGestureArea` and `rightViewSwipeGestureArea` to `.full`?